# Best Practice to Update MongoDB Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm sorry it's a technical question about how to implement transaction or pipeline in mongodb. So I have orders collection, in order document it has array of object which contains order items. In each order item, it has an array that contains material object. Let's say those materials are ingredients of an item, this object contains inventoryId and amount.

I have inventories collection which has availability property.

The order is finished so it needs to update the inventory availability based on material amount?

Here I give an example of the document.

```
// orders collection
{
    "_id": "SomeId",
    "items": [
        {
            "_id": "SomeId",
            "materials": {
                "inventoryId": "abc",
                "amount": 5,
            }
        },
    ],
}

// inventories collection
{
    "_id": "abc",
    "availability": 100,
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So you need to write an order and update 1 or more inventory docs.  This is an `insert` followed by a loop `update` inside a transaction session.  The calling details (not behavior) are highly driver language specific.  What language are you using?

Comment: Hi @BuzzMoschetti thanks for your reply. So do you mean I have to use loop for update each inventory? I'm using nodejs (expressjs).

Comment: Yes.   I am setting aside things like pre-checking to ensure there is enough inventory for the order, but yes -- you have to target the update to each inventory record (i.e. with a different `_id`) with a different amount.   Just wrap it all up in a javascript transaction session.

Comment: But if we have a lot of material items, it will cost a lot of database transaction if we do update in each inventory, won't it? @BuzzMoschetti